# how to set imge alt attribute by its div id by using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set image alt attribute via JavaScript.The problem is that image do not have id it self, All I have of its div Id.

```
<div id="logo">
<a href="http://yourwebsite.com">
<img alt="nkki" src="http://crankit.com.au/~thstarse/wp-content/themes/bigbangwp/image/logo.png">
</img>
</a>
```

What I am trying, however I am having no luck. Can anyone give me a hand with my code?

```
$(this).children('img').setAttribute('alt', 'new alt');
```

The Answer of this question is

```
document.querySelector("#logo img").setAttribute('alt', 'new alt');
```

Comment: Do you have many div with id and img inside it??

Comment: Please take a minute of your time and fix your spelling errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with pure javascript as well.

```js
document.querySelector("#logo img").setAttribute('alt', 'new alt');
```

Comment: Thanks, Finally i get my answer, you are right and its working in my wordpress website.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$('#logo').find('img').attr('alt', 'new alt');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y3p51mcg/)

Comment: It's working fine in fiddle. Which error occurred. @rohitnarang

Comment: hey, your code is absolutely correct but its not working in my websites. I am using wordpress and may be because of its...

Answer (score 2):

you can try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y3p51mcg/2/)

```
$("#logo img").attr("alt","alertnate image.jpg");
```